# npx react-native init AwesomeProjec ошибка завершилась с кодом ошибки 243

Tags: javascript, react-native

Суть такая решил попробовать написать программу под ios, делала все как по видео но выдает такую ошибку ( скажу заранее node.js обновил с оф сайта ), на запрос node -v / npm -v выдает версию и все ок, но когда пытаешься запустить сам react пишет следующее

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/roman/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/16/d2
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/roman/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/roman/.npm/_logs/2020-01-02T20_53_46_358Z-debug.log
Установка [ 'react-native@latest' ] завершилась с кодом ошибки 243
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо уже нашел решение вдруг кому-то пригодиться:

NPM locking error
If you encounter an error such as npm WARN locking Error: EACCES while using the React Native CLI, try running the following:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```